# Large deviation principle for small values of the maximum of the absolute value of a random walk

Tags: probability, random-walk, large-deviation-theory

Let $X_i$ be an i.i.d sequence of symmetric real random variables with variance 1 and $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$. Let $Z_n = \max_{1 \leq k \leq n } (|S_k|)$.
$Z_n$ is typically of the order of $C \sqrt{n}$. I am interested in the probability that $Z_n$ is very small compared to $\sqrt{n}$. 
More precisely
let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive real numbers diverging to $\infty$ such that $a_n/\sqrt{n} \to 0$. I am specifically interested in the case where $a_n = n^{1/3}$.
I am hoping of a result like $\frac{a_n^2}{n} \log P(Z_n \leq a_n ) $ converges to some known constant.
How can I get such a result?

Here are something I know but that are insufficient:

- This can be computed for the maximal absolute value of a standard Brownian motion when time goes to infinity as the distribution can be computed. but I am unable to find something similar for random walks or to use the Brownian limit by using explicit distribution of maximum which can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137263/maximum-of-absolute-value-of-a-random-walk).
- There exists positive constants $C,K,k, c$, such that for all $M \geq 1 $ and for $N$ large enough:

$ K\exp(-C N/M^2)\leq P(Z_N \leq a) \leq k \exp(-c N/M^2)$ which gives some reasonable hope that whar I am asking may be true. This can be found in *Potential theory and geometry on Lie groups* by Varopoulos (chapter 2 Annex  and chapter 5  (§5.12.1) ).

- I have tried to see if large deviation theory could help to prove this but I could not find anything and I don't know much about this topic, but this looks a bit like Cramér's theorem.

I am asking this question because I am reading Varopoulos book and I am trying to better understand the behavior of the random walk on certain amenable Lie groups but I don't think the context is very relevant to my question in this particular case.