# "Height" of the positive eigenvector of a non negative irreducible symmetric stochastic banded Toeplitz matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, toeplitz-matrices, stochastic-matrices

Let $ (a_n) $ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that  $\sum_{i = 0 }^\infty a_i = 1$. We assume that only a finite numbers of the $a_i$s are non zero. Let $M_d$ be the $d \times d$  symmetric (banded) Toeplitz matrix defined by:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \newline 
a_1 & a_0 & a_1  & a_2 & \cdots  &\cdots \newline
a_2  & a_1  & a_0  & a_1& a_2 & \dots \newline
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \newline
\end{pmatrix} $$

We further assume that $M_d$ is irreducible, at least for $d$ large enough.

By the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) $M_d$ has a (unique) eigenvector $\phi_d$ associated with the maximal eigenvalue $\lambda_d$  of $M_d$ and such that all the coefficients of $\phi_d$ are positive.

I am looking for an upper bound of the maximal ratio between two coefficients of this eigenvector, i.e.,

$$ \rho_d = \max_{0 \leq i,j \leq d-1 } \frac{\phi_d(j)}{\phi_d(i)} $$

A bound such as $\rho_d \leq C d $ where $C$ is a constant depending only on the $(a_i)$ would be ideal but any polynomial (or even larger) bound would be great. There are a few reasons that makes me think such a bound holds:

- it is true for tridiagonal (i.e $a_i = 0$ if $i \geq 2 $ ) matrices as the eigenvector can be computed in this case and is of the form $\phi_d(j) = \sin(\pi \frac{j+1}{d+1}) $. This fact can be found in the book [Spectral properties of banded Toeplitz matrices](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.978089871785) by Böttcher and Grudsky, chapter 12.
- the matrix is "close to stochastic" (when $d$ is big) so we could expect the eigenvector to be roughly uniform.

I am not very familiar with the theory of Toeplitz matrix and I am hoping this may be elementary even though I could not find anything like it in Böttcher and Grudsky book or elsewhere.

The rest of my question provides some context and is most likely irrelevant to solve the problem.
I am looking for such a bound as I am trying to find a quite sharp bound on the exit probability of a discrete random walk from an interval that is slowly growing with time . This is related to the ratio $\rho_d$ and to the asymptotic of $\lambda_d$. This asymptotic is very sharply known $ \lambda_d = 1 - \frac{\pi^2}{2 d^2} + O(\frac{1}{d^3}$) (see e.g. [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1993228) ) by  Widom.

Answering this question would also answer my previous question on [Large deviation principle for small values of the maximum of the absolute value of a random walk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664320/large-deviation-principle-for-small-values-of-the-maximum-of-the-absolute-value). I can explain why in more details if needed but I doubt, it's going to be relevant.